# Vector which is orthogonal to three vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to find a non-zero vector A which is perpendicular to three other vectors?

If so how would I do that? I can only find information on how to find an orthogonal vector to 2 other vectors.

Comment: @ ComputerScience in R^3?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in $\mathbb{R}^3$, if the three vectors are linearly dependent, then simply choose any two of them that span the subspace spanned by all three, and then find a vector orthogonal to those two.  If they are linearly independent, then none such exists, since then such a vector is orthogonal to all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and hence it is the zero vector.

Comment: You used linearly independent twice... I'm assuming if it's linearly independent then no orthogonal vector exists to the 3 vectors?

Comment: @ComputerScience523 yes sorry

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the dimension of your space.  If your vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then there are only three dimensions, and three mutually orthogonal vectors, for example $\{(1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T, (0,0,1)^T\}$.  If your vectors live in $\mathbb{R}^4$, then yes, there are four mutually independent vectors.

The procedure is similar to that in lower dimensions.  One way is to rotate the given vector onto one of the coordinate axes.  Then each axis defines one of the orthogonal vectors.  Now rotate all of the vectors back by the inverse rotation transformation.